Marketing Cloud Page try/catch question
I'm using ampscript to update Salesforce records using the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject function.  This happens after the cloud page posts to itself and I use the RequestParameter function to grab the form values.
SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Contact", @subscriberKey,
      "FirstName", RequestParameter("first_name"),
      "LastName", RequestParameter("last_name"),
      etc.....

I am trying to access those values in the catch but they are returning null.  The only variable I can seem to access is the subscriber key.  Is there a way I can access those parameter values?  My ultimate goal is to retrieve the original values and populate those on the form again so the user can try to resubmit.  Thanks
}catch(e){
    Write("UR" + Variable.GetValue("@updateRecord")); // returns null
    Variable.SetValue("errorMessage", Stringify(e.message) + Stringify(e.description));
    Write('<script>document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { showToast("ERROR", "Your changes have not been saved, please try again", "error"); });<\/script>');
  }


Please share more details... from where are you getting First_name , Last_name etc..
How many cloud pages are involved... from which page to which page do u wish to pass the values, what are the values you wish to pass.
